# Roo::spreedsheet can not open excel file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, roo

I'm trying to open excel file with `Roo::Spreadsheet` But it does not work.

```
workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
```

My file's  xls extension.

I can read it only when i open the file on my machine and i save as (.xls).

The thing i can not understand is that my original file is also .xls file.

**summary :**

original_file.xls

then:

```
workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
```

Result: does not work.

then: i open my file with excel, and save as (.xls).

```
workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
```

result: **IT WORKS**

Some help please.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually pass the file extension as param, Like as follows :

```
extension = 'xls'
workbook = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file, :extension => extension)
```

This has worked for me.